# Printing a date in DD\MM\YYYY format using only iostream?

Tags: c++, printing, cout

i have a class representing a date with 3 fields of unsigned int -

day, month, year.

i want to print to console in DD\MM\YYYY format, meaning adding leading zero if 
neccessary.

is there any way that can be achieved only with "iostream"?

i know that with "iomanip" it can be done easily with 'fill' and 'setw'.

and also, how to print the stray( \ ) char?

thanks

Comment: Why are your slashes left-handed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void PrintDate(unsigned day, unsigned month, unsigned year)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << day << "/" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << month << "/" << std::setw(4) << year;
  std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Edit:

```
void PrintDate(unsigned day, unsigned month, unsigned year)
{
  std::stringstream stream;

  if (day < 10)
  {
    stream << "0";
  }

  stream << day << "/";

  if (month < 10)
  {
    stream << "0";
  }

  stream << month << "/" << year;

  std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i mentioned - without using IOMANIP library, only with IOSTREAM ( if that's possible ).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Yes you could using if statements but seems messy.

Comment: I know that my friend, this is our assignment instructions. go figure.

i'll try the suggested code you posted after the edit, thanks.

Comment: No worries, let your teacher know they are asking stupid questions and are still stuck in the world of old code that is redundant now